# If $f:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ is continuous, prove that $f=e^g$ for some continuous $g:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm attempting to solve the above problem. I am supposed to use covering spaces to solve it but I cannot see a way of applying anything about covering spaces to the problem. I don't want the answer, I would just like a hint or an idea as to how to go about applying covering spaces to this problem. Thanks.

Comment: What are the universal covering spaces of a) $S^2$, and b) $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$?